# Regex working in Linux but not in windows - node.JS

Tags: regex, linux, windows, node.js

here's a little web-server function that gets a url and parses it, making sure that the client is not asking for a resource that's not under the server's root folder

```
function getUrl(url, resourceMap, rootFolder) {
    var path = require('path');
    if (typeof resourceMap[url] !== 'undefined') {
        return (path.join(rootFolder,resourceMap[url]));
    } 
    var absoluteURL = path.join(rootFolder,url);
    console.log("ROOT: "+rootFolder);
    console.log("NEW: "+absoluteURL);
    var regex = new RegExp('^' + rootFolder + '.*')
    if (absoluteURL.match(regex) === null) {
        console.log("FALSE");
        return (false);
    }
    return (absoluteURL);
}
```

As you can see I make sure that `absoluteURL` starts with `rootFolder` by using the regex `'^' + rootFolder + '.*'`

This worked well on Linux, but in windows it always returns false.

BTW the output is

```
ROOT: C:\Users\user\workspace
NEW: C:\Users\user\workspace\images\IMG_7102.JPG
```

So I know that parsing of the url is ok.

Amy ideas why?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, the `\`s in the path become escape characters in the regex.

You need to [regex-escape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969486/34397) it:

```
rootFolder.replace(/[-[\/{}()*+?.\\^$|]/g, "\\$&")
```

Comment: but rootFolder is assigned to be 'C:\\users\\workspace' so there shouldn't be a problem as far as i understand

Comment: @Yotam: I assume that's literal source.  Those escapes are for the string literal; the actual value of the string has single `\`s.